# How to compare line by line in two text in pig hadoop

Tags: apache-pig, cloudera

How to compare two text in pig

Example 
file 1 :

```
 1. 123456 raj kall dno 23  23-02-1984  xyz
 2. 123457 Tal dall dno 23  23-02-1985  xyz
 3. 123458 aaa fff  dno 23  23-02-1986  xyz
 4. 123459 gg  hhhh dno 23  23-02-1987  xyz
 5. 123460 aa  hhhh dno 23  23-02-1987  xyz
 6. 123461 bbb hhhh dno 23  23-02-1987  xyz
```

File 2:

```
 1. 123456 raj kall dno 23  23-02-1984  xyz
 2. 123457 Tal dall dno 23  23-02-1985  xyz
 3. 123458 aaa uuu  dno 23  23-02-1986  xyz
 4. 123459 gg  hhhh dno 23  23-02-1987  xyz
 5. 123461 bb  hhhh dno 23  23-02-1987  xyz
```

Expected output :

```
123458 aaa fff  dno 23  23-02-1986  xyz
123460 aa  hhhh dno 23  23-02-1987  xyz
123461 bbb hhhh dno 23  23-02-1987  xyz
```

Comment: I could not understand what are you trying to achieve. Do you want firstInput - secondInput?

Answer (score 0):

If you want A - B (the rows which are present in A but not in B), then use left outer join and check for  rows which have right side relation to be null.

```
A = LOAD 'file1' USING PigStorage() AS input:chararray;
B = LOAD 'file2' USING PigStorage() AS input:chararray;

C = JOIN A BY input LEFT OUTER, B BY input;
D = FILTER C BY B::input IS NULL;
E = FOREACH D GENERATE A::input;
```

I havent run the code. It might have syntax issues.
Hope this helps.

Comment: @ShivaN, if my answer has solved your question, please mark it as answered.